# can we block particular branch in aws code commit repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, branch, aws-codecommit

Right now we have few branches in aws code commit one of the repository like master , develop , release and main branches. I don't want any developer commit the code into main branch but i want that branch will be there only because we have code on that. How we will restrict that main branch

Answer (score 1):

You can do so via IAM policy restrictions on the User. Following documents provide the details on the steps required:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-conditional-branch.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/